# Simple way to monitor result of request to detect session timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, session, timeout

I've got an Ajax app I would like to add sessions and logins to.

Currently the app uses jQuery get shorthand to send a request

```
that.ajaxRequest = $.get(query_string, function(data, textStatus, xhr) { 

  // do somthing with data

});
```

I have a system on the server that throws an error message if the session has expired.

On the client I know I can deal with this using the following:

```
that.ajaxRequest = $.get(query_string, function(data, textStatus, xhr) { 

  if (data == "E_TIMEOUT") {

       // redirect to login

  } else {

       // do something

  }

});
```

However I would prefer not to have to write the same timeout code for every $.get - there are a bunch of them throughout the app.

Is there a way to monitor the result of a request and take action if necessary, without rewriting all of my $.get statements?

Thanks,

Comment: You really should be checking/validating the response that comes back.  You can make a specific function for that, to minimize the code you're adding to each callback.  if (dataChecker(data)) { } and dataChecker can be responsible for the redirection or other functions depending on the error message if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) for this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader('E_TIMEOUT') == "1") {
      //redirect to login
    }
  }
});
```

This approach is slightly different, it uses response headers which you can get *without parsing data an extra time every request* (that is possible, though not documented and subject to break), which you would have to do otherwise, in a global situation.

On the server-side where you're sending `E_TIMEOUT` for the response, just change it to add a header as well, `E_TIMEOUT=1` (or whatever header you want).  I actually put this header on my login page only, the timeouts redirect via a 302 (which XmlHttpRequest transparently follows), so if the user timeouts and the AJAX request actually ended up at the login page, I do a `location.reload()` to reflect this on the page.  That's just another option if you go that route, it looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  complete: function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader('LoginPage') == "1") {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
});
```

Without knowing what server platform you're using I can't say how to set headers, but it's pretty easy on every common platform.

Answer (score 0):

You should use firefox and download a program called 'FireBug'.  This will show you all the requests being sent out, and the response that comes back from the AJAX call.  It is action packed with goodness & web dev tools.